# Can two different chef-client coexist in the same host?

Tags: chef-infra

I'd need to determine if two different chef-clients can coexist in the same host, I'm aiming to point to two different chef servers with different versions and they require different chef-client versions.

Thank you!

Comment: why would you want a single client managed by more than one chef server?  The point of chef is consistency, and that sounds like a scenario that is begging for inconsistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question you asked, yes you can use two different config files and keep them isolated. You'll want to make sure the cookbook caches are in different folders so they don't stomp on each other, but otherwise it's fine.

Unrelated to that "they require different chef-client versions" is unlikely to be true. Chef-client 12 is compatible all the way back to Chef Server 0.9 I think, and definitely to at least 0.10. Similarly Chef Server 12 is compatible with all chef-client versions back to 0.9 and probably earlier. We try to be very careful to avoid backwards-incompatible API changes except when absolutely needed.

Comment: thank you coderanger! we're facing an issue with a customer keeping a chef-server v10 and we need to use chef-client v11+, that made us think to make up a different chef-server for our very own purposes with a newer chef-client whereas the chef-client v10 will still point to the old chef-server, although we need to still think about it thoroughly.